# Sending a non-client message to a WebSock process

Tags: websocket, elixir

The [WebSock documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/websock/0.5.3/WebSock.html#c:handle_info/2) states that the `handle_info/2` callback is

> Called by WebSock when the socket process receives a
> GenServer.handle_info/2 call which was not otherwise processed by the
> server implementation.

is there another, idiomatic way to send a message to a WebSock process from another process, that is not a websocket client?

Comment: Probably as with any other GenServer, you can just `Kernel.send/2` a message to the WebSock process.

Comment: The [WebSocket Lifecycle](https://hexdocs.pm/websock/0.5.3/WebSock.html#module-websocket-lifecycle) section of the documentation appears to suggest that handle_info/2 is the idiomatic way:
"WebSock will call the configured handler's WebSock.handle_info/2 callback whenever other processes send messages to the handler process"

Comment: @zwippie you're right, that is the idiomatic way to send a message from another process, handle_info just handles it. Please can you make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as with any other GenServer, you can `Kernel.send/2` a message to the WebSock process.